# How to debug the rancher server shutdown throwing with a normal message "SIGTERM RECEIVED"?

Tags: rancher, rancheros, rancher-rke

I am maintaining rancher single node setup. Recently we had a issue with the server and it is stopped. I tried to restore from backup. But still it fails. I am providing the log here. I am not able to debug the exact issue.

Rancher version 2.0.8
docker version: 17.03.2-ce

Restored from this documentation 
https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/backups/restorations/single-node-restoration/

```
2018/10/17 09:09:45 [INFO] Rancher version v2.0.8 is starting
2018/10/17 09:09:45 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains:[] AddLocal:auto Embedded:false KubeConfig: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:false NoCACerts:false ListenConfig:<nil> AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit.log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:3}
2018/10/17 09:09:45 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2018/10/17 09:09:45 [INFO] [certificates] Generating CA kubernetes certificates
2018/10/17 09:09:45 [INFO] [certificates] Generating Kubernetes API server certificates
2018/10/17 09:09:45 [INFO] [certificates] Generating Kube Controller certificates
2018/10/17 09:09:46 [INFO] [certificates] Generating Kube Scheduler certificates
2018/10/17 09:09:46 [INFO] [certificates] Generating Kube Proxy certificates
2018/10/17 09:09:46 [INFO] [certificates] Generating Node certificate
2018/10/17 09:09:47 [INFO] [certificates] Generating admin certificates and kubeconfig
2018/10/17 09:09:47 [INFO] [certificates] Generating etcd-127.0.0.1 certificate and key
2018/10/17 09:09:47 [INFO] [certificates] Generating Kubernetes API server aggregation layer requestheader client CA certificates
2018/10/17 09:09:48 [INFO] [certificates] Generating Kubernetes API server proxy client certificates
2018/10/17 09:09:48 [INFO] Running etcd --peer-client-cert-auth --client-cert-auth --name=etcd-master --listen-client-urls=https://0.0.0.0:2379 --initial-cluster-state=new --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-etcd-127-0-0-1-key.pem --data-dir=/var/lib/rancher/etcd/ --advertise-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://127.0.0.1:4001 --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2380 --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-etcd-127-0-0-1.pem --initial-cluster-token=etcd-cluster-1 --initial-cluster=etcd-master=https://127.0.0.1:2380 --listen-peer-urls=https://0.0.0.0:2380 --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-etcd-127-0-0-1-key.pem --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-etcd-127-0-0-1.pem
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver eks
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver eks done
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver import
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver import done
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver rke
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver rke done
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver import
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver import done
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver rke
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver rke done
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver gke
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver gke done
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver aks
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Activating driver aks done
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Running kube-apiserver --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname --storage-backend=etcd3 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver.pem --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-node-key.pem --requestheader-username-headers= --cloud-provider= --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-node.pem --tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305 --allow-privileged=true --admission-control=ServiceAccount,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota,DefaultTolerationSeconds --requestheader-allowed-names= --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem --insecure-port=0 --service-node-port-range=30000-32767 --proxy-client-key-file= --proxy-client-cert-file= --service-cluster-ip-range=10.43.0.0/16 --requestheader-client-ca-file= --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --advertise-address=10.43.0.1 --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1 --secure-port=6443 --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix= --requestheader-group-headers= --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --etcd-prefix=/registry --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver.pem --endpoint-reconciler-type=lease -v=1 --logtostderr=false --alsologtostderr=false
2018/10/17 09:09:49 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get https://127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=30s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Running kube-controller-manager --configure-cloud-routes=false --cloud-provider= --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubecfg-kube-controller-manager.yaml --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem --allocate-node-cidrs=true --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem --address=0.0.0.0 --allow-untagged-cloud=true --leader-elect=true --enable-hostpath-provisioner=false --node-monitor-grace-period=40s --v=2 --pod-eviction-timeout=5m0s --cluster-cidr=10.42.0.0/16 --service-cluster-ip-range=10.43.0.0/16 --use-service-account-credentials=true -v=1 --logtostderr=false --alsologtostderr=false --controllers * --controllers -resourcequota --controllers -service
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD apps.project.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD authconfigs.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD apprevisions.project.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD catalogs.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD clusteralerts.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD clusterevents.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Waiting for CRD apprevisions.project.cattle.io to become available
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD clusterloggings.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD clusterpipelines.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD clusterregistrationtokens.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD clusterroletemplatebindings.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:56 [INFO] Creating CRD clusters.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:57 [INFO] Creating CRD composeconfigs.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:57 [INFO] Done waiting for CRD apprevisions.project.cattle.io to become available
2018/10/17 09:09:57 [INFO] Creating CRD dynamicschemas.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:57 [INFO] Creating CRD globalrolebindings.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:57 [INFO] Creating CRD globalroles.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:58 [INFO] Creating CRD groupmembers.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:58 [INFO] Creating CRD groups.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:58 [INFO] Creating CRD listenconfigs.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:58 [INFO] Creating CRD nodedrivers.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:58 [INFO] Creating CRD nodepools.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:59 [INFO] Creating CRD nodetemplates.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:59 [INFO] Creating CRD nodes.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:59 [INFO] Creating CRD notifiers.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:59 [INFO] Creating CRD pipelineexecutionlogs.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:09:59 [INFO] Creating CRD pipelineexecutions.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:00 [INFO] Creating CRD pipelines.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:00 [INFO] Creating CRD podsecuritypolicytemplateprojectbindings.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:00 [INFO] Creating CRD podsecuritypolicytemplates.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:00 [INFO] Creating CRD preferences.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:00 [INFO] Creating CRD projectalerts.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:01 [INFO] Creating CRD projectloggings.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:01 [INFO] Creating CRD projectnetworkpolicies.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:01 [INFO] Creating CRD projectroletemplatebindings.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:01 [INFO] Creating CRD projects.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:01 [INFO] Creating CRD resourcequotatemplates.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:02 [INFO] Creating CRD roletemplates.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:02 [INFO] Creating CRD settings.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:02 [INFO] Creating CRD sourcecodecredentials.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:02 [INFO] Creating CRD sourcecoderepositories.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:02 [INFO] Creating CRD templatecontents.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:03 [INFO] Creating CRD templates.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:03 [INFO] Creating CRD templateversions.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:03 [INFO] Creating CRD tokens.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:03 [INFO] Creating CRD userattributes.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:03 [INFO] Creating CRD users.management.cattle.io
2018/10/17 09:10:04 [INFO] Starting API controllers
2018/10/17 09:10:04 [INFO] Starting catalog controller
2018/10/17 09:10:04 [INFO] Starting management controllers
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Reconciling GlobalRoles
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Listening on :443
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Listening on :80
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating catalogs-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating users-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating resourcequotatemplates-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-catalogs-manage for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-users-manage for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating user
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating settings-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-resourcequotatemplates-manage for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating podsecuritypolicytemplates-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-user for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating admin
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-settings-manage for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-podsecuritypolicytemplates-manage for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating clusters-create
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-admin for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating nodedrivers-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating catalogs-use
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-clusters-create for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating roles-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-catalogs-use for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating authn-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-nodedrivers-manage for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-roles-manage for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating user-base
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-authn-manage for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Reconciling RoleTemplates
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating admin
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating nodes-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-gr-controller] Creating clusterRole cattle-globalrole-user-base for corresponding GlobalRole
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating read-only
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating workloads-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating persistentvolumeclaims-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating edit
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating clusterroletemplatebindings-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating project-member
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating cluster-admin
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating projects-create
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating storage-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating create-ns
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating configmaps-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating serviceaccounts-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating ingress-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating ingress-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating cluster-owner
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating nodes-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating services-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating secrets-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating configmaps-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating projectroletemplatebindings-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating cluster-member
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating clusterroletemplatebindings-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating workloads-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating projectroletemplatebindings-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating services-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating persistentvolumeclaims-manage
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating projects-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating project-owner
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating serviceaccounts-view
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating new GlobalRoleBinding for GlobalRoleBinding globalrolebinding-xxn57
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] [mgmt-auth-grb-controller] Creating clusterRoleBinding for globalRoleBinding globalrolebinding-xxn57 for user user-ldpvp with role cattle-globalrole-admin
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating node driver amazonec2
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating node driver azure
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating node driver digitalocean
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating node driver exoscale
2018/10/17 09:10:05 [INFO] Creating node driver openstack
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] Creating node driver otc
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] Creating node driver packet
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] Creating node driver rackspace
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] Creating node driver softlayer
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] Creating node driver aliyunecs
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] Creating node driver vmwarevsphere
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] Rancher startup complete
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] uploading digitaloceanConfig to node schema
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] uploading digitaloceanConfig to node schema
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] uploading azureConfig to node schema
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] uploading azureConfig to node schema
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] uploading vmwarevsphereConfig to node schema
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] uploading vmwarevsphereConfig to node schema
2018/10/17 09:10:06 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:06 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.156.194:8960: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:07 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:07 http: TLS handshake error from 161.156.94.5:57806: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 35.198.157.174:45762: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 35.198.157.174:37512: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 35.198.108.65:33412: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 195.201.229.169:58888: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 161.156.94.6:7990: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 161.156.94.6:37752: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.184.119:37720: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.184.119:27448: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.122.247:60606: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.179.51:59498: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:30 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:30 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.179.51:18884: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:31 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:31 http: TLS handshake error from 95.216.156.231:59718: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:31 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:31 http: TLS handshake error from 95.216.152.252:60730: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:31 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:31 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.156.194:10544: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:32 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:32 http: TLS handshake error from 161.156.94.5:57892: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:32 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:32 http: TLS handshake error from 161.156.94.5:57894: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:33 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:33 http: TLS handshake error from 95.216.184.210:13944: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:34 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:34 http: TLS handshake error from 95.216.184.210:14014: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:36 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:36 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.156.194:10848: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:37 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:37 http: TLS handshake error from 161.156.94.5:57896: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:37 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:37 http: TLS handshake error from 161.156.94.5:57898: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:38 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:38 http: TLS handshake error from 95.216.184.210:14256: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:38 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:38 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.156.194:10952: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:38 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:38 http: TLS handshake error from 159.69.156.194:32978: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:38 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:38 http: TLS handshake error from 161.156.94.5:57900: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:38 [INFO] 2018/10/17 09:10:38 http: TLS handshake error from 161.156.94.5:57902: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Received SIGTERM, cancelling
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down NodeController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down CatalogController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down TemplateContentController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down ClusterRoleTemplateBindingController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down ProjectRoleTemplateBindingController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down SecretController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down SecretController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down RoleController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down ClusterRoleController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down RoleBindingController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down ClusterRoleBindingController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down ListenConfigController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down SettingController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down NodeDriverController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down DynamicSchemaController controller
2018/10/17 09:10:39 [INFO] Shutting down AuthConfigController controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to kubernates tls certificates expiry. Rancher version v2.0.8 does not have auto refresh mechanism for ssl/tls certificates. I have upgraded to v2.2.8, and the issue is fixed now. In v2.2.8 they have provided a solution for refreshing of kubernates certificates from the console.